# Deploy to Heroku from Node using React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, yarnpkg

Can someone help deploy my app to heroku, the code is available here:

https://github.com/b0bbybaldi/hippocrates

Heroku tells me to look into the link below but it is not very helpful...

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7494

I've been trying changing my package .json all day long but nothing seems to work, even though it runs just fine locally, and I keep getting the error below regarding dependency issues...

```html
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  v8.11.1
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       engines.yarn (package.json):  1.7.0
       
       Resolving node version v8.11.1...
       Downloading and installing node 8.11.1...
       Using default npm version: 5.6.0
       Resolving yarn version 1.7.0...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.7.0)...
       Installed yarn 1.7.0
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Running heroku-prebuild (yarn)
       yarn run v1.7.0
       $ cd client && yarn install
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 30.32s.
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.7.0
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning " > react-bootstrap@0.32.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0".
       warning " > react-bootstrap@0.32.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > prop-types-extra@1.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=0.14.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > react-overlays@0.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "react@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > react-overlays@0.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > react-prop-types@0.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=0.14.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > react-transition-group@2.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=15.0.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > react-transition-group@2.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=15.0.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > uncontrollable@4.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=0.11.0".
       warning " > react-router-dom@4.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=15".
       warning "react-router-dom > react-router@4.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=15".
       warning " > recompose@0.26.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 3.85s.
       Running heroku-postbuild (yarn)
       yarn run v1.7.0
       $ node scripts/build.js
       
       > login@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_05ea78b01ac233d426fddb05f3f82019/client
       > react-scripts build
       
       Creating an optimized production build...
       Compiled successfully.
       
       File sizes after gzip:
       
       105.45 KB  build/static/js/main.6de5e164.js
       430 B      build/static/css/main.51ce509b.css
       
       The project was built assuming it is hosted at the server root.
       You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
       For example, add this to build it for GitHub Pages:
       
       "homepage" : "http://myname.github.io/myapp",
       
       The build folder is ready to be deployed.
       You may serve it with a static server:
       
       yarn global add serve
       serve -s build
         
       Done in 20.46s.
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       yarn install v1.7.0
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning " > react-bootstrap@0.32.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0".
       warning " > react-bootstrap@0.32.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > prop-types-extra@1.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=0.14.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > react-overlays@0.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "react@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > react-overlays@0.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.9 || >=15.3.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > react-prop-types@0.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=0.14.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > react-transition-group@2.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=15.0.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > react-transition-group@2.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=15.0.0".
       warning "react-bootstrap > uncontrollable@4.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=0.11.0".
       warning " > react-router-dom@4.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=15".
       warning "react-router-dom > react-router@4.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=15".
       warning " > recompose@0.26.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       warning Ignored scripts due to flag.
       Done in 1.92s.
-----> Build succeeded!
 !     Unmet dependencies don't fail yarn install but may cause runtime issues
       https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7494
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 53.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v13
       https://ancient-dusk-89840.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: So you don't get the warnings about missing dependencies when building locally? Provide a *minimal* example which reproduces the error.

Comment: Would be helpful if you can describe more. Have you updated the app before? What do you see after you are done with this update? Meanwhile not sure if it would help but I would try to delete the `package-lock.json` locally then run `npm install` then try deploy again.

Comment: Hi thanks for chipping in... It was probably missing dependencies, I gave up with yarn and switched to npm, did all the installation process and it worked!